# Merge two arrays of odd and even numbers in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I'm working on a JavaScript problem, that's as follows.

So I have two arrays with odd and even numbers in them, as follows.

A = [1,3,5,7]
B = [2,4,6,8]

I want to merge them such that the resulting array is like:

C = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I've tried to use concat (), but I don't think that's the way to go.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    let A = [1,3,5,7];
    let B = [2,4,6,8];
    let C = A.concat(B).sort();
    console.log(C);
```

You can can concat and sort like below

```
    let A = [1,3,5,7];
    let B = [2,4,6,8];
    let C = A.concat(B);
    console.log(C.sort())
```

You can also do it with simple for loop,

```js
    let A = [1,3,5,7];
    let B = [2,4,6,8];
    let C = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        C.push(A[i]);
        C.push(B[i]);
    }
    console.log(C)
```

If you want to use reduce,

```js
        let A = [1,3,5,7];
        let B = [2,4,6,8];
        const C = B.reduce((result,current)=> result.concat(current), A).sort();
        console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let A = [1,3,5,7];
 let B = [2,4,6,8];
 let C = [];
 let j = 0;
 let k = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <=8 ; i++) {
       if( i % 2 != 0)
       {
          C.push(A[j]);
          j = j + 1;
       } else {
          C.push(B[k]);
          k = k + 1;
       }
    }
    console.log(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple just do it like:

```
  const A = [1,3,5,7];
  const B = [2,4,6,8];
  console.log(A.concat(B).sort());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the es6 features and sort it afterwards:

```
const a = [1,3,5,7];
const b = = [2,4,6,8];

const c = [...a, ...b].sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

You can read more about sort [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

its very easy, simple solution to your problem

```
var a = [1,3,5,7];
var b = [2,4,6,8];

console.log([...a,...b].sort())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .concat() with .sort() subsequently.
E.g.

```js
const A = [1,3,5,7];
const B = [2,4,6,8];

const C = A.concat(B).sort();

console.log(C);
```